# Why POST request is not getting sent?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest

Creating CRUD application. I am able to send GET requests, but other requests are not getting sent.

The below line is causing error.

```
await Book.create(req.body);
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const books = require('./routes/api/book');

const app = express();

connectDB();

app.use('/api/books', books);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Starter Code</h1>')
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

**routes/api/book.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// Load book model
const { Book } = require('../../models/Book');

// @route GET api/books/test
// @description tests books route
// @access Public
router.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Book route testing!');
});

// @route GET api/books
// @description get all books
// @access Public
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const books = await Book.find();
        res.json(books);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404);
        res.json({nobooksfound: 'No Books found'});
    }
});

// @route GET api/books/:id
// @description get single book by id
// @access Public
router.get('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const book = await Book.findById(req.params.id);
        res.json(book);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404);
        res.json({ nobookfound: 'No Book Found' });
    }
});

// @route POST api/books
// @description add or save book
// @access Public
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        await Book.create(req.body);
        res.json({msg: 'Book added successfully'});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            error: 'Unable to add this book'
        })
    }
    
});

// @route PUT api/books/:id
// @description update book
// @access Public
router.put('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const book = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body);
        res.json({
            msg: 'Updated Successfully'
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(400);
        res.json({
            error: 'Unable to update the Database'
        })
    }
});

// @route PUT api/books/:id
// @description delete book
// @access Public
router.delete('/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const book = await Book.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, req.body);
        res.json({msg: 'Book entry deleted successfully'});
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(404);
        res.json({error: 'No such book'})
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**models/Book.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String
    },
    published_date: {
        type: Date
    },
    publisher: {
        type: String
    },
    updated_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Book = mongoose.model('book', BookSchema);
```

Comment: what's the error you are getting? Does the line of code execute and just not work as intended, or is it not even reached?

Comment: Your title appears to be incorrect. the post request is being sent, the server is receiving it, and an error is occuring.

Comment: @ChristianFritz the line is getting executed but it then goes to the catch block

Comment: Yes, @KevinB you got it right

Comment: Nikita, you say it goes to the catch block but in that catch block you're *not* printing the error? why not? that would be the obvious way to debug this.

Answer (score -1):

Error is you have not used body-parser. Replace **app.js** code with the below one.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const connectDB = require('./config/db');
const books = require('./routes/api/book');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

connectDB();

app.use('/api/books', books);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Starter Code</h1>')
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8082;

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

Answer (score -2):

You are telling it to await. But await what. You must create a Promise to wait for.

Somewhere in you model you are going to need to create a Promise.

```
//here is an example so you can see the flow. I know it's mysql and not mongo, but a promise is a promis

pullWhiteList: async (phone) => {

        data = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            sql = "SELECT c.name AS client_name, w.* FROM api_whitelist w INNER JOIN api_client c ON w.client_id = c.client_id WHERE phone LIKE ? ORDER BY phone ASC LIMIT 10;";
            db.query(sql, [phone + '%'], (err, res, fields) => {
                if (err) {
                    resolve(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(res);
                }
            });
        })

        return await data;
    },
```

Comment: This isn't necessary for the mongoose model method being awaited. It does support async/await.

Comment: Good to know. I do not use mongoose, So please good sir, enlighten us to an answer.

Comment: My guess is the other answer is correct, but absent an error message, we can only assume.

Comment: Yes. Thank you.